# inserting and reading data to/from athena tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I apologise if the title is a bit misleading for the question I am going to ask. I am trying to understand how athena works a bit more clearly.

I have a daily job, which uploads files to a s3 location. I have created a athena table, which reads table from that s3 location. Every day the data gets updated and new files (i.e. new data) is uploaded to the location. (New necessarily doesn't mean overwriting but also adding more files).
My issue is, when I try to read the latest data from athena gui, it doesn't return anything but an empty table.

How do I read the latest data? Do I have to run another command like `ALTER TABLE` or `INSERT INTO` after uploading files to s3. My understanding was uploading files to that s3 location is akin to inserting data into table and vice versa i.e. running `ALTER TABLE/INSERT INTO` is akin to uploading files to s3?

Comment: Do you glue as metadata store as well? Are the files partitioned and do you have partitions set up in glue? You may be missing a partition for the newly added daily data.

Comment: I haven't used glue at all. Although, I am storing files in s3 in such a manner that it represents partition i.e. if I want to partition with year, month, day the files are stored at the location `s3://..../year/month/day/df.csv`. I assumed that if the files are stored as such, they are partitioned and athena can take this into account while querying.

Comment: Just to clarify, tables exist in glue as metadata explaining what and where data resides in s3. Even if you create table in the Athena ui using the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command, this results in a glue table being created. If you use a crawler it also creates a glue table. It seems you are close, but showing the DDL command or type of crawler that created the table would be helpful.

Comment: yes, the table exists in glue. are you implying to see the latest data from s3 in athena, I have set up a crawler job which updates the data in aws glue? (have to admit, I didn't know about glue when posting this question)